Phonetic difference between English affricate /dʒ/ and /tʃ/ at the onset of stressed syllables
I'm having difficulty distinguishing between the pronunciation of two words Joke and Choke from Cambridge Online Dictionary (UK pronunciation). Here're the links for the two sounds:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/english/uk_pron/u/ukj/ukjoc/ukjocul025.mp3
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/english/uk_pron/u/ukc/ukcho/ukchock009.mp3

To my ears, it sounds like the /dʒ/ in Joke in the above recording has been completely devoiced (and this is typically for lenis sounds if they occur at the onset of stressed syllables in UK pronunciation as I can see).
Suppose that /dʒ/ has been devoiced, then is there any phonetic difference between it and the fortis counterpart? If no, then is there any acoustic difference between the recordings of Joke and Choke above?

at first blush, without having listened to the clips, I'd expect joke to begin [tʃ] and choke to begin [tʃʰ]

The primary distinguishing feature between ‘voiced’ and ‘unvoiced’ occlusives in initial position is indeed aspiration in most forms of English, as @Tristan says. For the ‘voiced’ consonants, both voiced realisations (with negative VOT) and unvoiced realisations (with zero VOT or short, positive VOT) are common, but the ‘unvoiced’ consonants will always be aspirated (with a long, positive VOT). Note that in some Englishes (especially Indian English), the difference is normal voiced vs voiceless, with no aspiration.

ch is voiceless and j is voiced with the same articulation, so it's sometimes tricky to hear them. jest and chest is another example.

@Tristan That's what I thought of at first. But, it's hard to interpret [h] in [tʃʰ]. Let alone [h] itself is hard to interpret as prof. Wells put it here: https://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/04/h-fricative-or-approximant.html.

@TranKhanh [ʰ] is not the same as [h]. Regardless, [tʃʰ] has a clear phonetic interpretation, it is a postalveolar affricate with +ve voice onset time (i.e. voicing only starts significantly after the closure's release, where [tʃ] would indicate voicing starts around the same time as the closure's release, and [dʒ] that voicing starts before the closure's release)

@Lambie this is emphatically not the case. "Voiced" stops are frequently voiceless unaspirated in English, and distinguished from "voiceless" stops solely by aspiration. The fact the OP specifically brings up devoicing as typical of lenis sounds in this position makes it clear they know this

@Tristan, I took a basic acoustic analysis and wrote an answer based on your comment, it would be helpful if you could revise it.

This is wrong? https://sandiegovoiceandaccent.com/american-english-consonants/how-to-pronounce-the-ch-%CA%A7-and-j-%CA%A4-consonants

@Lambie, it's not really wrong. But English "voiced" consonants are not reliably voiced, especially if they're at the beginning or end of a word. Thus, the terms lenis and fortis are preferred rather than voiced and voiceless.

@Lambie yes. In many positions the "voiced" obstruents of English are not voiced at all. This is well-established by experimental phoneticians. The exact details vary by dialect and speaker, but a simple statement that j is voiced and ch is voiceless is oversimplified to the point of falsehood

@TranKhanh It's like glottal stops. Half of them seem odd to me.

SE from the early 2010s: Diachronic devoicing of initial lenis plosives in English

@Lambie, the waveform for glottal stop would be flat, IIRC.

As @Tristan pointed out, there's a brief puff of air inserted between /ʃ/ and the diphthong in choke as shown in the below sound wave:

The fortis also generates a stronger energy, showing by a denser ban of purple color.
